# Does Amazon Redshift have table switch as SQL Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been searching in docs but I don't see a single statement such as:

```
ALTER TABLE Source SWITCH TO Target
```

Is there an equivalent in Amazon Redshift?

Comment: you mean - change the table name?

Comment: no, the switch statement changes the pointer to the data in the files partitions.

Comment: No, there is no concept in Redshift for what that command appears to be in SQL Server. What are you actually wanting to accomplish in Redshift?

Comment: Just swapping partitions of stg table and final table to achieve faster processes.
Instead of copying data from s3 to stg table, and then inserting to final. I just insert to stg and if process succeed then swap. Otherwise final data is not touched and data still available despite being 'old'

Answer (score 0):

In the Redshift world, that kind of operation is more closely aligned with [external table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html) partition management through Amazon Redshift Spectrum.

There's no table level switch like your example, but for external tables you can add and remove partitions and switch *paths*, which is nearly the same. There are some syntax examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_external-table.html)